# Angular 4 create different language path route to the same component

Tags: angular, multilingual, angular-router

I want to create the multi-language support for the website. I'm currently using ngx-translate to translate all the text . Let's way we have two urls, mypage/en/home and mypage/es/home. How can I create those language paths and route them to home component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated based on comment:

In the routes for the router you can do something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: 'mypage/:language/home', component: HomeComponent
  }
]
```

This way you actually only need one route and can have as many languages as you want.

Then in your component you can do:

```
public constructor (
  route: ActivatedRoute
){
  this.language = this.route.snapshot.params['language'];  
}
```

If you really want multiple routes, you can do something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes =[
  {
    path: 'mypage/en/home', component: HomeComponent
  }
  {
    path: 'mypage/es/home', component: HomeComponent
  }
]
```

Comment: I know ngx-translate my separate .json files for each language. But I want to create the language path like mypage/en/home , mypage/es/home, just want to create an extra language path, the route will detect that language path to translate accordingly.

Comment: nice... I'll try this ml route setting