# Change page URL on language change in Angular 5 with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

The problem in question is, how to change the URL routes defined in the routing module on language change with ngx-translate?

The challenge is that routes are predifined, and the only possible solution that I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297894/4275425), but is not quite what I'm looking for.

What I need is to change the route home_[lang] (for example) on every language change like this:

```
https://baseurl/home_en
```

to

```
https://baseurl/home_es
```

Every time the user changes language.

Is it possible?

I also saw [this issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/40) but still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a parent route that receives the *home_language* and have children routes. Like this:

```
const  appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':home_language', component: LanguageComponent, children: [
    //all your toutes here
    { path: 'route1', component: Component1 },
    { path: 'route2', component: Component2 }
  ] }
];
```

So you wiull have this routes:

```
/home_es/route1
/home_es/route2
/home_en/route1
/home_en/route2
```

And in the LanguageComponent template, you should add a *router-outlet* so the components from the children routes will be loaded there.

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```